# TextMate Snippet to Mirror Only Matched Characters

Tags: regex, textmate, boost-regex

I have been trying unsuccessfully to mirror text that only matches "a-z0-9" using the following code:

```
${1/[a-z]/$0/}${1}
```

After the snippet has been tab triggered I would expect to type "$test" and see "test" mirrored.

Any clues?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet beneath removes all $, % and ? from either beginning or end of your text. Note that the regular expression is added and applied to the mirror, not to the input itself.

```
$1 ${1/[\$\?%]*([^\$\?%]*)[\$\?%]*/$1/} $0
```

If you want to exclude more characters, add those to each class (escape them if necessary).

Comment: I can't believe I finally have an answer after over a year! Thank you very much :D